# priority-web-sdk: Record already exists in form

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, erp

So I have a [nodejs http handler](https://github.com/SimonBarnett/apiLoad/blob/master/apiHandler/apiHandler/util.js) that accepts [JSON input](https://github.com/SimonBarnett/apiLoad/blob/master/clientExample/output.json) and parses it into a [recursive class](https://github.com/SimonBarnett/apiLoad/blob/master/apiHandler/apiHandler/Loading.js). The [handler](https://github.com/SimonBarnett/apiLoad/blob/master/apiHandler/apiHandler/util.js) then iterates through the contents of the class, populating data into the appropriate columns, forms and sub-forms.

If there are no already existing records this [works fine](https://github.com/SimonBarnett/apiLoad/blob/master/apiHandler/apiHandler/Output.html).

```
util.get('/', function (req, res) {

    var requestBody = '';
    var msg;
    var curform;

    req.on('data', function (data) {
        requestBody += data;
    });

    req.on('end', function () {

        var ld = new Loading(null, JSON.parse(requestBody));
        Login(ld, curform).then(() => {
            res.simpleJSON(200, ld.log.toJSON)
        }).catch(() => {
            res.simpleJSON(200, ld.log.toJSON)
            })        

    });

    function Login(ld, curform) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            console.log("Connecting...");
            priority.login(config).then(() => {
                console.log("Opening form %s.", ld.name);
                priority.formStart(ld.name, null, null, 1).then(curform => {
                    curform.clearRows().then(() => {
                        iter(ld.rows, iterRow, curform).then(curform => {
                            console.log("Close form %s.", curform.name);
                            curform.endCurrentForm().then(() => {
                                resolve()
                            }).catch(err => { ld.log.setError(null, null, err); reject(err) })
                        }).catch(err => { ld.log.setError(null, null, err); reject(err) })
                    }).catch(err => { ld.log.setError(null, null, err); reject(err) })
                }).catch(err => { ld.log.setError(null, null, err); reject(err) })
            }).catch(err => { ld.log.setError(null, null, err); reject(err) })
        })
    }

    var iterRow = function (m, curform) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
             iter(m.columns, iterField, curform).then(curform => {
                console.log("Saving form %s.", curform.name);
                curform.saveRow(0).then(() => {
                    m.sucsess();
                    iter(m.subLoadings, iterForm, curform).then(curform => {  
                        if (m.$index < m.parent.rows.length-1) {
                            console.log("New row in form %s.", curform.name);
                            curform.newRow().then(() => {
                                resolve(curform)
                            }).catch(err => reject(err))
                        } else {
                            resolve(curform)
                        }
                    }).catch(err => reject(err))
                }).catch(err => {
                    m.fail(err);
                    resolve(curform);
                })
            }).catch(err => reject(err))                   
        })
    }

    var iterForm = function (m, curform) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {  
            console.log("Opening sub form %s.", m.name);
            curform.startSubForm(m.name, null, null).then(curform => {
                curform = curform;
                console.log("New row in form %s.", curform.name);
                curform.newRow().then(() => {
                    iter(m.rows, iterRow, curform).then(curform => {
                        console.log("Closing sub form %s.", curform.name);                        
                        curform.endCurrentForm().then(() => {                                                        
                            resolve(curform);
                        }).catch(err => reject(err))
                    }).catch(err => reject(err))
                }).catch(err => reject(err))
            }).catch(err => reject(err))        
        })
    };

    var iterField = function (m, curform) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {   
            console.log("Set field %s = %s.", m.name, m.value);
            curform.fieldUpdate(m.name, m.value).then(() => {
                resolve(curform);
            }).catch(err => {
                if (err.message == "Record already exists in form.") {
                    SelectRow(m, curform).then(() => {
                        resolve();
                    }).catch(err => reject(err))
                } else {
                    reject(err)
                }
            })                
        })
    }

    /* Iterate function */
    function iter(ar, fn, result) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {    
            try {                 
                var cntr = 0;
                function next() {
                    if (cntr < ar.length) {
                        ar[cntr].$index = cntr;                
                        fn(ar[cntr], result).then(curform => {
                            cntr++;
                            next();
                        }).catch(err => reject(err));
                    } else {resolve(result)};
                };
                next();        
            } catch (err) { reject(err)}    
        })
    }

});
```

However, if the record already exists in the form the [fieldUpdate](https://prioritysoftware.github.io/api/form/#fieldUpdate) of course throws the `"Record already exists in form."` error. The question is how best to handle this.

In the parent form I can simply use [ClearRows](https://prioritysoftware.github.io/api/form/#clearRows) so that the [fieldUpdate](https://prioritysoftware.github.io/api/form/#fieldUpdate)s will open the record if it exists. But this does not seem to be supported on sub-forms.

Similarly, I could use a [setSearchFilter](https://prioritysoftware.github.io/api/form/#setSearchFilter) and [setActiveRow](https://prioritysoftware.github.io/api/form/#setActiveRow) (only calling [newRow](https://prioritysoftware.github.io/api/form/#newRow) if the length of the [getRows](https://prioritysoftware.github.io/api/form/#getRows) is zero) but again, the [setSearchFilter](https://prioritysoftware.github.io/api/form/#setSearchFilter) seems to be only supported in the parent form.

Given these limitations I also considered using an unfiltered [getRows](https://prioritysoftware.github.io/api/form/#getRows) on this error, to identify the existing record and [setActiveRow](https://prioritysoftware.github.io/api/form/#setActiveRow) like this:

```
function SelectRow(m, curform) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        curform.undo().then(() => {
            curform.getRows(1).then(rows => {
                var cntr = 1;
                while (rows[curform.name][cntr] !== undefined) {
                    var f = 1;
                    for (var i in parent.rows[m.$index].columns) {
                        if (rows[cntr][parent.rows[m.$index].columns[i].name] !== parent.rows[m.$index].columns[i].value) {
                            f = 0;
                        }
                    }
                    if (f == 1) {
                        curform.setActiveRow(cntr).then(() => {
                            resolve();
                        })
                    } else { cntr++; }

                }
                resolve();

            }).catch(err => reject(err))
        }).catch(err => reject(err))
    })
}
```

But having called the [undo](https://prioritysoftware.github.io/api/form/#undo) method the [getRows](https://prioritysoftware.github.io/api/form/#getRows) function then returns no results.

Any suggestions please?

Comment: A bit hard to understand the question.Can u summarize it somehow? At least the code sample.

Comment: Sorry for the delay- holidays etc. Basically the question is how to filter subforms. For this specific application though I've gone with an [oData client](https://github.com/SimonBarnett/apiLoad) instead.

Comment: Filtering subforms is not supported yet :) Meanwhile you can retrieve all the rows and then filter the result in the client or use REST API as you did. Nice work combining REST API and WEB SDK!!